# Dynamically changing HTML with experss.js

Tags: html, model-view-controller, express

I am not sure whether I got the idea of express MVC right:

If I want to make a single page app and dynamically change the HTML, is it something express can help me with? or do I get static pages that if I want to change I have to use front-end JavaScript?

To be more specific, the HTML (or Jade) templates can can change the HTML that is in the front-end somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I want to make a single page app and dynamically change the HTML, 
>   is it something express can help me with?

Yes.

> or do I get static pages that if I want to change I have to use 
>   front-end JavaScript?

Yes, you will need to use JavaScript in the front-end to change the pages if you don't want to refresh the entire page.

> To be more specific, the HTML (or Jade) templates can can change 
>   the HTML that is in the front-end somehow?

Typically the HTML (or Jade) templates that you use in Express.js will produce the initial version of the page.

As the user interacts with the page on the browser (say the user clicks on a link or selects something from a dropdown list) your client-side code will submit an Ajax request to the server, Express.js will process this request and return JSON (not HTML) back to the client, and your front-end JavaScript will repopulate some data on the client. Keep in mind that at this point you won't be producing more HTML from the server, though.

Your Express.js could return HTML instead of JSON for these requests but that gets messy pretty quick so most people writing Single Page Apps chose to return JSON back to the client and use client-side JavaScript to repopulate whatever DOM elements need to be updated.

Comment: so it's like PHP in this way, I get a static page and can make AJAX calls, but can't "remotely" modify the HTML itself?

Comment: Correct. There is no conceptual difference in this case.